# How to remove items from context menu in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

I would like to remove the items in red frames shown in the image below:

[image: context menu]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a good article on how to modify context menus.](http://www.winvistaclub.com/e11.html)

Always be careful when dabbling with the registry.